# Angular 6 add jquery, popper and bootstrap js

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with angular 6 and sass bootstrap project and i'm trying to add jquery, popper and js in angular.json

My code in angular.json is :

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

i have tried this also :

```
 "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
        ]
```

but toggle and dropdown dosnt work for me .

Comment: add only the css files under script tag

Comment: doesn't  work . i need to add scripts  dependencies to make everything work

Comment: did you stop and run again `ng serve` to compile?

Comment: i did but doesn't work. whats the best way to add js in angular 6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 npm install bootstrap to install boostrp
 npm install jquery to install jquery and add path under the 'build' inside 
 angular.json

"styles": [
          "src/styles.css", "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
"scripts": ["node_modules/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"]

Please verify the file inside the node_modules.
```

Comment: this my current version :  "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]

Comment: please provide your angular.json file

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WCB_u4bD4g1Ir_e2_uBZmp2Z3-zh31rozwN3QiwEMNE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WCB_u4bD4g1Ir_e2_uBZmp2Z3-zh31rozwN3QiwEMNE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: As per your json file there is no "styles": [
             "src/styles.scss"
           ],
           "scripts": [
             "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
           ]